# How to set an image as background of a Form in React Native?

Tags: react-native, styles, background-image

i have been working on a form in which i need to get a background image to make it look more beautiful. when i use form components inside the image tag it shows the following error 
  [image]

im giving the code below that i used

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {Image,View,Dimensions,ImageBackground} from 'react-native'

let {height,width}=Dimensions.get('window')
class DearImage extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <View >
       <Image source={require('../drawable/Auntie.jpeg')}
         width={width}
         height={height} >
        {this.props.children}
       </Image>        
     </View>    
   );
 }
}

export default DearImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your error shows* you need to set your **Image** to **absolute** position, to avoid this you can use **ImageBackground** .and **Image** Tag *cant have any children tag directly*, *Use a View instead* well use like the below code, **it will work for you**

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react' 
import {Image,View,Dimensions,ImageBackground} from 'react-native' 

let {height,width}=Dimensions.get('window') 
class DearImage extends Component { 

render() { 

return ( 

<ImageBackground 
 source={require('../drawable/Auntie.jpeg')} 
style={{ 
backgroundColor: '#ccc', 
flex:1, 
width: '100%', 
height: '100%', 
justifyContent: 'center', 
}} > 

<View style={{flex:1,position:"absolute", backgroundColor: 'transparent', }}> 
{this.props.children} 
</View> 
</ImageBackground > 

) 
} 
} 

export default DearImage;
```

Comment: if you dont mind what is this <ImageBackground> tag for i couldn't see any documentation on it or any code

Comment: that you imported wrongly , thats not needed Hari, you just need to import Image

Comment: there is no tag like ImageBackground

Comment: yes i tried and its not working the same error pops up again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163620/discussion-between-thunder-and-harikrishnan-s).

Comment: this will be your final file code as we tested and it worked for you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163652/discussion-between-thunder-and-harikrishnan-s).

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <Image source={require('../drawable/Auntie.jpeg')}
               width={width}
               height={height}>                            
        </Image>  
        <View style={{flex:1,position:"absolute"}}> 
               {this.props.children}
        </View>
        </View>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageBackground instead of Image.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {Image,View,Dimensions,ImageBackground} from 'react-native'

let {height,width}=Dimensions.get('window')
class DearImage extends Component {

render() {

    return (
        <ImageBackground source={require('../drawable/Auntie.jpeg')}
          width={width}
          height={height}
          style = {{flex:1}}>
            {this.props.children}
        </ImageBackground>        
    )
}
}

export default DearImage;
```